# Creating observable from submit event

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, rxjs

**Disclaimer**: I'm super new to both Angular and RXJS.

I have a simple form from which I'm trying to create an observable. This will  look for `submit` events and update some value in the component. However, I'm getting a `this._subscribe is not a function` error.

```html
<form (submit)='submitForm()'>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**My component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import UtilsHelperService from '../services/utils-helper.service';

@Component({...stuffs...})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  formSubmit: Observable<any>;
  counter = 0;
 
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    this.formSubmit = Observable.create(form, 'submit');
  }

  submitForm() {
    this.formSubmit.subscribe(
      UtilsHelperService.formSubmitObserver(this.counter));
  }
}
```

**And my `utils-helper.service.ts` helper class...**

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export default class UtilsHelperService {
  static formSubmitObserver(counter) {
    return {
      next: (value) => {
        counter++;
      },
      error: err => console.log(err),
      complete: () => console.log('complete')
    }
  }
}
```

- I see that the `formSubmit` observer is created fine.
- I have the `UtilsHelperService.formSubmitObserver` method that returns an `observer` object with the 3 necessary methods.

So, I'm not sure whether if it's the Angular stuffs I'm doing wrong (which I guess not) or its the RXjs stuff. Thank you for your time reading it :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at FormGroup. Its 'valueChanges' property is an observable you can subscribe to.

```
FormGroup formGroup;

// populate your formGroup (https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-1-creating-a-formgroup-instance)

formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(// do whatever you want);
```

Comment: I am using reactive-forms and it's valueChanges to grab values from input field (omitted from the example). Just wanted to create my own observable to understand how it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 things I did to solve the issue:

1. Using `fromEvent` instead of `Observable.create` to create observable from `submit` event. This way the subscription didn't threw error (investigating why..)
2. Updating component property from service won't work as the services are singletons. You either have to use eventemitter or use AngularJS styles dot rule. For this case, I added all the helper logic in the component itself.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
  this.formSubmit = fromEvent(form, 'submit');
  this.formSubmit.subscribe((submitEvent) => {
    this.counter++;
    this.formSubmitted.emit(this.counter);
  })
}
```

With this I can remove the `submitForm` method from the component and template and the helper method from the service.